# Starting a 'For Each As DataGridViewRow' at a specific Row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

Currently I have a function that searches through every row in my DataGridView and looks like so.

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
 Next
```

However due to an issue caused by something else I need to make it start the For Each Row at a specific row.
I've tried "For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(RowToStartAt)" However this appears to be the wrong method to use.

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible or not? Or have I just tried to use the wrong method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this kind of syntax

```
For Each row in dgv.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Skip(5)
    Console.WriteLine(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString())
Next
```

In this example the loops skips the first 5 rows and then starts its enumeration

Not sure if this is really beneficial or not. A traditional for ... loop is probably more clearer but as Linq goes this achieve the result required.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly. My initial issue was because somethign related to my timer caused it to stop at the 35th row every time when the delay was set to 1000. And if I changed the delay to 100 it'd stop at 4 and if set to 10000 it'd stop at the 350th row. I hope this answers helps anybody with a similar peculiar issue!

Comment: @Crystalwolf I know the post is over 2 years old - but I think and perhaps you later discovered - your timer event triggered a cross thread operation. The timer runs on a separate thread and when the event elapses that method is not running on the forms thread. This is probably what caused it to stop at a specific row - the cross thread exception. You needed to use invoke in your timer elapsed method - I would guess that you were trying to update the UI from that event.